# I am getting python2 failed errors on npm install some error not solve

Tags: python, node.js, npm

```
rade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\jay\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe E:\jay\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'E:\\jay\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E:\jay\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:400:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\jay\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd E:\jay\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.17.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saurab kumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-07T13_17_15_805Z-debug-0.log
```

I thought I have try this command not working wright now
**npm install --global windows-build-tools** what will be do?

Comment: The offending package needs to update their code to use Python 3. Python 2 has been unsupported for going on 3 years, and deprecated long before that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using vue app in docker (yesterday it worked fine, today I got this error [and I did not really change anything])
Anyway, I just need app for testing so I tried to use older node-sas version ([this change in package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU4SR.png)) and it worked again